# Python copy a list to a new list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, copy

I wanna copy a list into new list here my code which is not works:

```
l = list(range(0,101,2))
n = []

def change(l):
    for i in range (len(l)):
        k = l.copy()
        n[k] = l[:] 


print (l)
print (n)
```

I wanna copy the l list into the n list,but it not works.
Thanks the help in advance.

Comment: Thats because `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'`

Comment: don't overcomplicate things, `n=l` done.

Comment: @hansTheFranz no, this does not copy the list, n and l both point to the same list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>>l = range(0,101,2)
>>>n = [x for x in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

```
import copy
n = copy.copy(l)
```

To avoid the following problem with `n = l`:

```
l = list(range(0,21,2))
n = []
n = l
l.append(1000)
print (n) #=> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 1000]
```

Comment: You can also do the following: n = l[:]

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to copy the list without using any module is `n = l[:]`:

```
l = list(range(0,101,2)) # get list of even values from 0 to 100
n = l[:]                 # copy data from l to n
print (l)                # check data of l
print(n)                 # check data of n
l.pop()                  # remove last element from l
print(l)                 # It prints only 0 to 98
print(n)                 # It prints from 0 to 100 (can you see here, changing l doesnot impact n)
```

Now if you use `n = l` directly then any change in `l` will change the value in `n`, check below code:

```
l = list(range(0,101,2))

n=l
print (l)                # check data of l
print(n)                 # check data of n
l.pop()                  # remove last element from l
print(l)                 # It prints from 0 to 98
print(n)                 # It prints from 0 to 98
```